# Merge two Media Sources together

Tags: c#, uwp

I have run to a brick wall in this particular situation where I have to merge two `MediaSources` together, one for video and one for audio, and then play that in `MediaPlayerElement`.

I have searched google a lot but haven't found anything relating to it. The actual problem is that I get two `Urls` and I can create two `MediaSources` from them but I cant put those two sources in the player source, because when i do it either plays the video or the audio depending upon which was the last source.

So I basically created two `MediaPlayerElement`s and assigned different sources to them and try to sync the audio and video between them but sometimes it creates awful results. I have also thought about creating two streams and then combining those two to create a single stream but I dont know anything about streams so I am not able to do that yet.

Any suggestions here? Maybe a 3rd party library which works in UWP and can help me here? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying, adding players and trying to sync is a duct tape solution :), could work, but you will probably have issues.

As you did not mention I'm assuming you need to support various formats for audio/video, which if you go with your current solution you will need to test every possible combination to be sure it works.

The proper way to merge audio and video is to merge the streams, a great (and free) tool you can use for this is FFMPEG, you can use a wrapper for the command line that works with UWP [found here](https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop), it also has a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FFmpegInterop.UWP/). It supports a lot of formats and is very fast as it's written in C.

Comment: I dont think a command line library would work with UWP. Would it?

Comment: It's not compatible with UWP 14393 version.

Comment: You are right, I use this in forms :) so just pasted, updated the answer with a lib that support UWP

Comment: I know that one, there is no support for merging any streams in that package. You can create a MSS (Media Stream Source) from a URI but I have two URIs so the problem is still there. Plus creating a Media Stream Source within UWP requires one or two Media Descriptors and creating those for Video is rather an advanced task because it involves DirectX frame decoding.

Comment: I've used FFMPEG to merge downloaded files (streams), it also supports RTSP so it should be able to merge those as well (haven't researched this). If you are trying to do this on the fly in memory it will be quite advanced any way you try to approach it. Maybe you can buffer the streams and merge them with slight lag if that works for you.

Comment: Yeah I can look into that. Thanks